# Only Pin 5 working on multiple Cat5E cables

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, cable

I have CAT5e cable running through my home for landline, and I'm repurposing it for internet. I terminated the ends of each cable with a RJ45 punch down keystone. I then tested it with a network tester. Most of the cables work as expected, however I have multiple cables where only pin 5 is flashing on either tester. Is there something specific with that pin number? That would be odd if both cables happened to be damaged, except for wire 5. Would love some feedback on this, thanks!

Comment: There is nothing special about pin 5, which is in the center of the jack and is the W-BL wire of a standard 4pr cable. Without knowing the tester and what flashing means specifically it is hard to say. Note that W-BL is half of the normal pair used for dialtone, W-BL/BL-W, and it is very common to see these cables used in a residential unit looped through multiple outlets in parallel with the jacks, so the possibility of data connectivity issues is higher.

Comment: @acejavelin thanks for the info. The tester just checks to make sure each wire/pin is communicating, and shows a light for each pin. The cables in the house were never used, and each one runs back to a central location in the basement

Comment: So, what is there at the other end of a cable that you are testing with your tester?

Comment: @Caleb So it is just a basic continuity tester... OK. when you say "keystone" do you mean you are putting an RJ45 crimp end on the cable, or terminating them on a cat5e jack that you would plug a patch cord into?

Comment: @acejavelin it's a keystone jack, then I plug in patch cables to both ends.

Comment: @Caleb Could be bad connection or punch down, bad or damaged cable or any number of things. FWIW, 10/100 ethernet only uses pins 1, 2, 3, and 6, Gigabit uses all 8 pins.

Comment: Check your tester's documentation.  I suspect it's an error code of some sort.